# Google showing "This site maybe hacked" under search result

Tags: search, console, google-search

For some malware, google shows this under search result of Duggal Visual Solutions. Fixed all of them on 23rd november, asked for review. No response from them. 3 days ago, I've updated sitemap, submitted on google, updated robots.txt, fetched and rendered all the problematic urls. Those urls shows a 404.
But the notice is still there. Google isn't doing anything. What should I do now to remove this? Company is losing customers for this. Is there any way to contact google directly?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the right site this, since this isn't about *programming* per se. It's about what Google thinks of your website. You *might* look at [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - I think they accept digital marketing type questions, but do your research for topicality before posting it there.

Comment: Thanks :) I appreciate that.